# ORA-00904 invalid identifier only on hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I'm getting a invalid identifier error, but only on hibernate.
If i copy the query from the hibernate log and run it on my SQL client, it works like a charm.

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MCI_USER", schema = Constantes.DB_SCHEMA)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class User implements Entidade<Integer>, Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "NOME")
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "NUIT")
    private String nuit;

    @Column(name = "ATUALIZADOEM")
    private LocalDate atualizadoEm;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ATUALIZADOPOR")
    private Usuario atualizadoPor;

    @Column(name = "CRIADOEM")
    private LocalDate criadoEm;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CRIADOPOR")
    private Usuario criadoPor;

    //getters and setters
```

Usuario.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Usuario", schema = Constantes.DB_SCHEMA)
public class Usuario extends User implements UserDetails {

    @Column
    private String senha;

    @Column
    private String chaveApi;

    @Column
    private boolean ativo = true;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "usuario", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<PerfilDoUsuario> perfis = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "IdUnidade")
    private Unidade unidade;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idDepartamento")
    private Departamento departamento;

    //getters and setters...
```

Create Table Script:

```
CREATE TABLE mci_user
(
    Id    INTEGER generated as identity NOT NULL,
    Nome  VARCHAR(1000)    NOT NULL,
    Email VARCHAR(200)     NOT NULL,
    NUIT  CHAR(9),
    criadoPor     int,
    criadoEm      timestamp,
    atualizadoPor int,
    atualizadoEm  timestamp,

    CONSTRAINT PK_User PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);

CREATE TABLE usuario
(
    Id             INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Senha          VARCHAR(1000)    NOT NULL,
    ChaveApi       VARCHAR(32),
    Ativo          NUMBER(3)              NOT NULL,
    IdUnidade      INT,
    IdDepartamento INT,

    CONSTRAINT PK_Usuario PRIMARY KEY (Id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Usuario_User FOREIGN KEY (Id) REFERENCES mci_user (Id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Usuario_Unidade FOREIGN KEY (IdUnidade) REFERENCES unidade (IdUnit),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Usuario_Departamento FOREIGN KEY (IdDepartamento) REFERENCES departamento (Id)
);
```

The error log:

```
12:11:23,629 INFO  [stdout] (default task-16) Hibernate: select usuario0_.ID as ID1_11_, usuario0_1_.CRIADOEM as CRIADOEM2_11_, usuario0_1_.CRIADOPOR as CRIADOPOR7_11_, usuario0_1_.ATUALIZADOEM as ATUALIZADOEM3_11_, usuario0_1_.ATUALIZADOPOR as ATUALIZADOPOR8_11_, usuario0_1_.EMAIL as EMAIL4_11_, usuario0_1_.NOME as NOME5_11_, usuario0_1_.NUIT as NUIT6_11_, usuario0_.ativo as ativo1_30_, usuario0_.chaveApi as chaveApi2_30_, usuario0_.idDepartamento as idDepartamento5_30_, usuario0_.senha as senha3_30_, usuario0_.IdUnidade as IdUnidade6_30_ from mci.Usuario usuario0_ inner join mci.MCI_USER usuario0_1_ on usuario0_.ID=usuario0_1_.ID where usuario0_1_.EMAIL=?
12:11:24,759 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-16) SQL Error: 904, SQLState: 42000
12:11:24,760 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-16) ORA-00904: "USUARIO0_1_"."ATUALIZADOPOR": identificador inválido
```

Using oracle 12c and hibernate 5

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late, but from what I see it fails just in the atualizadoPor  attribute because it is of type Usuario, and in the Usuario class you have not defined the id attribute which is the primary key

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Usuario", schema = Constantes.DB_SCHEMA)
public class Usuario extends User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

...
```